Inductor value effect on the performance of a buck circuit
In the following circuit (LT8640S-2, synchronous step-down
regulator) based on the reference design I needed to use 1.5 uH.
I applied 11.6V (my battery voltage
) I got 5V at the output and 3A. The minimum voltage at the input that I can get is 5V in the output is around 7.5V.

I adjusted the value of the inductor to 4.5 µH and observed that the minimum input voltage required to achieve 5V output increased to approximately 14V. This indicates that the value of the inductor influences the input voltage range. I am now exploring the underlying reasons for this behavior and would like to know if there is an equation that explains this relationship.

What is the DC resistance of the 4.5uH inductor? Was that output voltage with load?

Have you tried simulating the circuit? What's the duty cycle when the voltage goes below 5V?

The datasheet has plenty of guidance on choosing the various components along with equations. Note that there is not one ‘best’ solution - there are many compromises involved. If you know your circuit will be powered by, say, a 12V psu, then you don’t need to factor in a wide input voltage range. Similarly knowing your load characteristics- will the load be constant? These factors allow you to fine tune the design. Also note that you will need to iterate as the first pass gets you in the ballpark, then you can tweak values to optimise. Rinse and repeat.

Andromeda, One thing immediately comes to mind from a quick scan of the datasheet. With 4.7 uH, you likely need a capacitor to ground from Vc (in parallel to the added zero there.) Also, are you running spread spectrum for this testing? If so, what happens if you disable it? (Just curious.) Finally, it takes a much higher voltage across the inductor to get the dI/dt to where it may need to be. I'd need to think more about it to develop a formula for this complicated device, especially running spread spectrum. Don't have much to add right now.

The inductor should be sized so that at max DC current, the ripple current is about 30%. This is related to switching frequency. The lower the frequency, the larger the inductor needs to be to achieve that operating condition.
